# Retrieving imageURL from Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imageurl, share-extension

I am trying to get the `imageURL` the ios share extension uses for the thumbnail generated in the `action sheet`.

I am retrieving the `URL` fine but cannot seem to figure out how to get the `imageURL`.

Here is how I get the normal `URL`,

```
 if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
        if let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {      
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeItem as String) {
                itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeItem as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in
                    if let shareURL = url as? NSURL {

                        let components = URLComponents(url:shareURL as URL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
                        if  let host = components?.host { self.shareTitle = host }
                        self.shareURL = shareURL.absoluteString!                            
                        self.POSTShareData(completion: nil)
                    }
                    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried to changing the `typeIdentifier` to `kUTTypeImage` to no avail. I have my `info.plist` set to `NSExtensionActivationRule` to `TRUEPREDICATE` to see what I can retrieve. I am thinking maybe I have to be more explicit in the `.plist` ??

I am targeting iOS 9.3

Comment: @salman Ghumsani, I  do not want to download the image I just want the URL the share extension uses. In the link you provided I am not seeing how he retrieved the url.

Comment: I'm not sure this is achievable. I believe the NSItemProvider's `previewImageHandler` can return either a URL or a Data object, and those are used internally to present a thumbnail, but aren't technically part of the shared payload, and therefore wouldn't be available to a share extension.

Comment: i think you can convert url into string and  then can split string at / and further you can split each index with . by using perhaps you will be able to get the extensions used in url.

Comment: Please note that in your completion handler the first parameter is of type NSSecureCoding. Not in all cases a URL is coerced but it could also be Data or even in some rare cases an UIImage-object. see my post/question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219339/ios-swift-share-extension-what-are-all-and-the-best-ways-to-handle-images

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is that you can store that URL link in common UserDefaults

eg:- let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.common.Notification")

Then access it in-app or extension